# jquery datepicker todate button not visible when date in textbox is less than mindate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have start date, end date, display date and suggested date (by overriding the todate button) options in the jquery datepicker.

Every thing works fine till the time I set display date less that min date using code. At this point Today button becomes invisible.

I do not want this behavior. Today button should always be visible.

Can some one please suggest why is this happening and what should be done to correct this.

Thanks!!! Help will be appreciated...

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/2y8kdno8/[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y8kdno8/)

```
function createDatePicker(calendarName) {
    $(function () {
        var $controlName = $("#" + calendarName),
            startDate = $controlName.attr('startDate'),
            endDate = $controlName.attr('endDate'),
            suggestedDate = $controlName.attr('suggestedDate'),
            preSelectedDate = $controlName.attr('preSelectedDate');

        $controlName.datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: startDate,
            maxDate: endDate,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            currentText: "Suggested Date",
            closeText: "X",
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            autoSize: true,
            showAnim: 'drop'
        }).val(preSelectedDate)
            .attr("readonly", true);
        $.datepicker._gotoToday = function (id) {
            $(id).datepicker('setDate', suggestedDate).datepicker('hide').blur();
        };
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("font-size", "x-small");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    createDatePicker('fromPackagingDate');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's doesn't make much sense. If there is a minimum date why would you set the current date to be inferior? You can always change dynamically the minimum date like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", /*Your date here*/);
```

Comment: Well, u can say its a requirement. Dates stored in DB can be in past as well so onload they should be presented but on save validation should be made with accordance to minDate. Thats why it is required. Also your suggestion will change the minDate which is not the expectation. http://jsfiddle.net/2y8kdno8/